# getting error "machineDefinition is undefined" I already follow steps?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, fsm

I am using below package for demo application

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@opuscapita/fsm-workflow-core

I follow all steps whatever it is written in doc .But getting error 
**machineDefinition is undefined**

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-banzai-xumr2?file=/src/index.js

```
var http = require("http");

let { MachineDefinition, Machine } = require("@opuscapita/fsm-workflow-core");

var machineDefinition = new MachineDefinition({
  schema: {
    initialState: "start",
    finalStates: ["finish"],
    transitions: [{ from: "start", event: "run", to: "finish" }]
  }
});

const object = { status: "none" };
const machine = new Machine(machineDefinition);
machine
  .start({ object })
  .then(({ object }) => {
    console.log(machine.currentState({ object }));
    // start
    return machine.sendEvent({ object, event: "start" });
  })
  .then(({ object }) => {
    console.log(machine.currentState({ object }));
    // finish
  });

//create a server object:
http
  .createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.write("Hello World!"); //write a response to the client
    res.end(); //end the response
  })
  .listen(8080); //the server object listens on port 8080
```

could you please tell me where I am doing wrong .?

One more thing this package is `Apache-2.0` licence .can I use this package in my real project ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I played around with that package a bit and found it to be a bit buggy. I fixed the problem your having, however, I ended up running into another one. You're passing the correct argument into the Machine constructor function but there is a problem within the package. If you read into it you will see that there is a conditional that explicitly throws an error if it doesn't see the very object you're passing in. Sorry I couldn't help more but I hope this at least got you closer to the goal.